# Looping based on grouping of account transactions

Tags: sql, loops, t-sql, cursor

I've been thinking about how to resolve this without using looping or cursors and I think I have a way but I am having issues coding it.

I have a table that has rows of transactions grouped by acctnumbers (RN is row number or each account partition) for example:

```
INSERT INTO REVERSAL_TEST (AcctNumber, TxnDate, TxnCode, TxnAmount, RN)
VALUES('80780245',  2015-12-22,   51,   143.71,           1),
    ('80780245',    2015-11-16, 1,  -143.71,          2),
    ('80780245',    2015-11-6,  51, 143.71,         3),
    ('80780245',    2015-11-6,  71, -33.44,           4),
    ('80780245',    2015-10-23, 1,  -143.71,          5),
    ('80780245',    2015-9-17,  1,  -143.71,         6),
    ('80780245',    2015-8-11,  1,  -143.71,          7),
    ('71627499',    2015-4-10,  51, 315,              1),
    ('71627499',    2015-4-3,   1,  -315,             2),
    ('71627499',    2015-3-10,  1,  -325,             3),
    ('71627499',    2015-3-10,  51, 325,              4),
    ('71627499',    2015-3-10,  51, 325,              5),
    ('71627499',    2015-3-4,   1,  -325,             6),
    ('71627499',    2015-2-10,  51, 325,              7),
    ('71627499',    2015-2-3,   1,  -325,             8),
    ('71627499',    2015-1-31,  51, 315,              9),
    ('71627499',    2015-1-14,  1,  -315,             10),
    ('71627499',    2014-12-9,  51, 325,              11),
    ('71627499',    2014-12-5,  1,  -325,             12),
    ('82345872',    2016-8-17,  51, 716.58,           1),
    ('82345872',    2016-8-5,   1,  -238.86,          2),
    ('82345872',    2016-7-28,  71, -477.72,          3),
    ('83495429',    2018-08-20, 51, 600.00,         1),
    ('83495429',    2018-08-20, 51, 600.00,         2),
    ('83495429',    2018-08-20, 71, -600.00,         3),
    ('83495429',    2018-08-17, 1,  -200.00,        4),
    ('83495429',    2018-07-20, 1,  -200.00,         5),
    ('83495429',    2018-06-25, 1,  -200.00,         6);





    AcctNumber  TxnDate       TxnCode   TxnAmount   RN
    80780245    12/22/2015 0:00 51  143.71           1
    80780245    11/16/2015 0:00 1   -143.71          2
    80780245    11/6/2015 0:00  51  143.71           3
    80780245    11/6/2015 0:00  71  -33.44           4
    80780245    10/23/2015 0:00 1   -143.71          5
    80780245    9/17/2015 0:00  1   -143.71          6
    80780245    8/11/2015 0:00  1   -143.71          7
    71627499    4/10/2015 0:00  51  315              1
    71627499    4/3/2015 0:00   1   -315             2
    71627499    3/10/2015 0:00  1   -325             3
    71627499    3/10/2015 0:00  51  325              4
    71627499    3/10/2015 0:00  51  325              5
    71627499    3/4/2015 0:00   1   -325             6
    71627499    2/10/2015 0:00  51  325              7
    71627499    2/3/2015 0:00   1   -325             8
    71627499    1/31/2015 0:00  51  315              9
    71627499    1/14/2015 0:00  1   -315             10
    71627499    12/9/2014 0:00  51  325              11
    71627499    12/5/2014 0:00  1   -325             12
    82345872    8/17/2016 0:00  51  716.58           1
    82345872    8/5/2016 0:00   1   -238.86          2
    82345872    7/28/2016 0:00  71  -477.72          3
    83495429    2018-08-20 00:00:00 51  600.00       1
    83495429    2018-08-20 00:00:00 51  600.00       2
    83495429    2018-08-20 00:00:00 71  -600.00      3
    83495429    2018-08-17 00:00:00 01  -200.00      4
    83495429    2018-07-20 00:00:00 01  -200.00      5
    83495429    2018-06-25 00:00:00 01  -200.00      6
```

What I need to do is get the date of the last valid transaction, which is a transaction that has NOT been reversed which is TxnCode 51.
So for example, in the above sample data, for account 80780245 the last TxnDate would be the 71 txn on 11/6/2015 since the 51 txn on 12/22 reverses the $143.71 txn on 11/16/2015 and the 51 txn on 11/6/2015 reverses the 143.71 txn on 10/23.

For Acctnumber 71627499 the last txn date would be on 3/10/2015 for the $325 txn. The 51 txn on 4/10 reverses the 1 txn on 4/3

For AcctNumber 82345872 51 reverses the sum of the next 1 and 71 so the last txn date is NULL

For AcctNumber 83495429 the first 2 txns are 51 so it would be added on to the 51 total and reverses the sum of the 1 and 71 so the last txn date is NULL

```
 Sample output:
80780245    11/6/2015
71627499    3/10/2015
82345872    NULL
83495429    NULL
```

I understand that there may be a lot of edge cases and the exact specs are very fuzzy as it is with the real world project I am working on.

I thought about using a cursor or while loop but I am working with many accounts and not sure if it would be feasible to run as performance would be horrible.

I was thinking about creating a temp table/view with the following schema:

```
    AcctNumber 51Total  Sum1 Sum2 Sum3 Sum4......
```

Where 51Total would a running total of the 51 txn's and sum1 would be the first value of the txn where the txncode is 1 or 71, sum2 would be the sum of the value of sum1 + the next value of txncode of 1 or 71, etc....
 Then I can run through and see which sumX would net out the 51Total and that would be the number of txn's to go down to get the txn date. 
This should be faster than using a while loop or cursor, however, I am having issues coding this. 
Can someone help me with how to access the previous 1 and 71 txns and sum them when building the table?
Another issue I am having issues with the last case above where the first 2 txn's are 51, then I would need to add those 2 and 51Total would have the sum of these values and SUM1 would have the value of the first 01 or 71 txn which would be RN = 3.

I am using this code but I am not sure how to get the sum of sum1 and the next 1 1 or 71 value in sum2. Also, how to deal with the scenario when there are 2 51 txn's that I need to sum up before I reach a sum value that nets the 51value

```
    SELECT 
         r.AcctNumber
        ,MAX(CASE WHEN r.RN = 1 THEN r.TxnAmount ELSE NULL END) AS '51Total'
        ,MAX(CASE WHEN r.RN = 2 AND r.TxnCode <> '51' THEN r.TxnAmount ELSE NULL END) AS 'SUM1'
        ,MAX(CASE WHEN r.RN = 3 AND r.TxnCode <> '51' THEN r.TxnAmount ELSE NULL END) AS 'SUM2'
    FROM #ReversalAccountTxnDetails r
    GROUP BY r.AcctNumber
```

I am open to any other solution that greater minds can help me think of.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. It helps to identify the database software and version (TSQL narrows the choices), provide sample data in a consumable form (e.g. a table variable declaration and `insert` statement) and the expected output.

Comment: I have tried plugging your data into excel and doing a running total to see if I can work out which rows you want. I don't understand your logic. Something as simple as `select AcctNumber, sum(txnamount) as amt from @t group by AcctNumber` shows that all but 80780245 sum to zero, which means they are all reversed. So I don't understand your explanation of why you want to see some of these transactions and not others.

Comment: How can a reversal transaction (51) have a row number less than the transition(s) it is cancelling? Is that correct?

Comment: Added insert statement and sample output. Input is a list of txns grouped by acctnumber ORDERED by txndate DESC so the smaller row number would show a later transaction. The final output would be a list of those acctnumbers with the last valid transaction date which is a transaction that has not been reversed by a 51 txn. So basically if you are auditing the txn's to an account, you would look at the txn history. If a payment was made (1 or 71) that would be the last txn date, but if there is a 51 txn occurred later that matches or is a sum of previous txn's those txns are not valid.

Comment: I think I am able to resolve this. I created a few temp tables for pre-processing and I have it working now.